# detect whether the checkbox is checked using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

i am trying to find if a checkbox([[image: Checked Checkbox]])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6am9N.png)

is checked or not. till now i tried using the method used in [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/).i am trying to see if there are any triangles in the image. if there is at least one triangle it means that the checkbox is checked. The problem i found is that, sometimes the outer rectangle is being detected instead of triangles. how should i ignore rectangle and detect only triangles

Comment: That tutorial from pyilagesearch is capable of differentiating between different shapes based on vertices.. why don't you use that?

Comment: i tried it. i used Harris corner detector. but, i was getting too many points in the for the image.

Comment: I've been solving this task sometime ago. I had dataset of checked/unchecked checkboxes, and upon these data i've built classifier. I've tried Random Forest, KNN and both algorithms gave me almost perfect results. Also they were quite fast.
Dataset was quite small, about 40 sample per class

Comment: Thanks, i have a CNN solution for this. i wanted to do it using opencv.

Comment: i guess image contains either rectangle(unchecked) or rectangle with diagonals(checked), in this case you can either check the pixel density and use certain predefined threshold to classify that. Or else you can analyze the contour hierarchy to classify.

Comment: @flamelite , thanks man. i think i can use contour hierarchy, i am exploring about it. if you already know enough about it, can you help me understand it on how to use it for my problem.

Comment: @Dmitry hey, what are your inputs for the algorithms (contours, hierarchy, ????). I am working on a similar project. Would appreciate if you could send me some link for reference.

Comment: @ChauLoi sorry for a very late reply. If I am not mistaken, I used just the raw pixels, and fed them into to the classifier.

Comment: @InAFlash I too working on the similar I had an image with some checkboxes and I detected all the checkboxes using find contours can you say how can I check whether they are checked or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you don't even need to use hierarchy information, Just count the number of contours and use to classify your image.
I am giving a simple python implementation to view the individual contours.

Contour hierarchy representation in OpenCV has been explained here [Contour Hierachy](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)

```
img = cv2.imread(r'D:/Image/cross.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,bw = cv2.threshold(gray,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_CCOMP,1)
cntLen = 10
ct = 0 #number of contours
for cnt in contours:
    if len(cnt) > cntLen: #eliminate the noises
        ct += 1
        newimg = img.copy()
        cv2.drawContours(newimg,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.imshow('Win', newimg)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
print('Total contours: ',ct)
```

Comment: hey, I wonder if you have any better method because this method for my case is not good. Please check out my works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907802/best-way-to-detect-if-checkbox-is-ticked

Answer (score 4):

I ended up needing to do something very similar to this and had to determine whether or not 2,500-ish envelopes had a check on them.  Using the answer here, I was able to do it with about a 10% error rate.  I ended up doing the following, instead:

First I fed my 'Unchecked' samples through a PixelDensity script.  I'm checking for the number of 'white' pixels:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
import functools

whitePixelAverage = []

path = "./"
included_extensions = ['png','PNG']

allFiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if any(f.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)] # Get all files in current directory

length = len(allFiles)

for i in range(length):
    img = cv2.imread(allFiles[i], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    imgCrop = img[655:713,692:767] # Select your ROI here, I allow for a bit of deviation between image scans
    n_white_pix = np.sum(imgCrop == 255)
    print('number of white pixels: ', n_white_pix)
    whitePixelAverage.append(n_white_pix)
print(whitePixelAverage)
print("Average: ", functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y,whitePixelAverage)/len(whitePixelAverage))
print("Lowest: ", min(whitePixelAverage))
print("highest: ", max(whitePixelAverage))

t = input(":") # Wait for input to close
```

From this selection, I ended up taking my 'Lowest' value and giving it a Threshold of 3% (in my case this was about 117).

Now, I do the same, but this time feed it a sample of 'Checked' boxes.  The White Pixel density of these should be, on average, lower.

For my checked boxes, I use the Average.  I end up comparing the Average of the Checked boxes to the lowest+threshold of the unchecked:

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
import os
import shutil
import functools

path = "./testSet/"
checkedP = "./testSet/checked/"
uncheckedP = "./testSet/unchecked/"
included_extensions = ['png','PNG']

THRESHOLD = 117

allFiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if any(f.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)] # Get all files in current directory

length = len(allFiles)

for i in range(length):
    img = cv2.imread(path+allFiles[i])
    imgCrop = img[655:713,692:767]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgCrop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,bw = cv2.threshold(gray,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    _,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_CCOMP,1)
    cntLen = 1
    ct = 0 #number of contours
    for cnt in contours:
        if len(cnt) > cntLen: #eliminate the noises
            ct += 1
    print('Total contours: ',ct)
    if ct >= 3:
        print("Checked!")
        shutil.move(path + allFiles[i], checkedP + allFiles[i])
        img = cv2.imread(checkedP+allFiles[i], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        imgCrop = img[655:713,692:767]
        n_white_pix = np.sum(imgCrop == 255)
        if (n_white_pix > 3747+THRESHOLD):
            shutil.move(checkedP + allFiles[i], checkedP+"Unconfident/")
        averageWhitePixels.append(n_white_pix)
    else:
        print("Not so checked")
        shutil.move(path + allFiles[i], uncheckedP + allFiles[i])
        img = cv2.imread(uncheckedP+allFiles[i], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        imgCrop = img[655:713,692:767]
        n_white_pix = np.sum(imgCrop == 255)
        if (n_white_pix < 3747+THRESHOLD):
            shutil.move(uncheckedP + allFiles[i], uncheckedP+"Unconfident/")
```

Comparing Pixel Density in addition to flamelite's answer, I was able to reduce my error rate from 10% to about 2.47% over 2,500 different samples.

I apologize for how inelegant my code is.  This is my first answer, please let me know if anything is too terrible.  There are most likely lots of things left in there that I used for troubleshooting.

Hope this helps!