# OpenCV checkbox detection and if checked

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, omr, document-layout-analysis

I'm working on a scanned document to verify if a checkbox is checked or not.
The form contains 3 checkboxes and are being checked off by humans.

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK1re.png)
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhOtx.png)

I am having difficulties isolating the 3 checkboxes and determine if it is checked or not.
First script tries to find the boxes and mark them. I try to reduce the results found but it isn't getting better.
https://github.com/Koffiemolen/ReadCheckBoxes

```
# pip install fitz
# pip install PyMuPDF
# pip install opencv-python numpy Pillow

import fitz
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *

# Example code:
# https://towardsdatascience.com/convert-pdf-to-image-in-python-using-pymupdf-9cc8f602525b

# You should run pip install fitz followed by pip install PyMuPDF. If you have install PyMuPDF, uninstall it and
# install again.
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467667/how-do-i-resolve-no-module-named-frontend-error-message

# sourceDir: C:/Temp/checkbox/Src
# destDir: C:/Temp/checkbox/Output

# Local folders
sourceDir = 'C:/Temp/checkbox/Src/'
dirPNG = 'C:/Temp/checkbox/PNG/'
destDir = 'C:/Temp/checkbox/BoxHiglight/'

# To get better resolution
zoom_x = 2.0  # horizontal zoom
zoom_y = 2.0  # vertical zoom
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom_x, zoom_y)  # zoom factor 2 in each dimension

# Iterate over files
pdfFiles = glob.glob(sourceDir + "*.pdf")

# Iterating PDF files and export to PNG
for filename in pdfFiles:
    print('Reading file: ', filename)
    doc = fitz.open(filename)  # Open document

    # Getting filename without path and extension
    name = filename.split('.')
    filename = name[0].split('/')
    filename = filename[-1].split('\\')

    for page in doc:  # Iterate through the pages
        print('Processing page: ', page.number)
        pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)  # Render page to an image

        # Saving PNG
        print('File saved: ', dirPNG + filename[1] + "page-%i.png" % page.number)
        pix.save(dirPNG + filename[1] + "page-%i.png" % page.number)  # Store image as a PNG


# Checking checkboxes

# Variables
pngFiles = glob.glob(dirPNG + "*.png")  # Only select png files
i = 0  # Counter
showImages = False  # Set to true to not save files, instead show files

print(pngFiles)  # Print files that are being processed

# Iterate over files
for filename in pngFiles:
    print('Reading file: ', filename)

    # Read image into array
    inputImage = cv2.imread(filename)

    # Check array type
    type(inputImage)

    # output: numpy.ndarray

    # Prepare a deep copy for results:
    inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

    # Converting image to gray scale
    grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Image thresholding
    _, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    binaryImage = 255 - binaryImage

    # Image thresholding v2
    # _, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Show image
    if showImages:
        Image.fromarray(binaryImage).show()

    # Using morphological operations to identify edges
    # Set min width to detect horizontal lines
    line_min_width = 7

    # Kernel to detect horizontal lines
    kernel_h = np.ones((1, line_min_width), np.uint8)

    # Kernel to detect vertical lines
    kernel_v = np.ones((line_min_width, 1), np.uint8)

    # Horizontal kernel on image
    img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_h)

    # Vertical kernel on the image
    img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_v)

    # Show image with horizontal lines only and vertical lines only
    if showImages:
        Image.fromarray(img_bin_h).show()
        Image.fromarray(img_bin_v).show()

    # Combining the image, horizontal + vertical
    img_bin_final = img_bin_h | img_bin_v

    # Show combined image
    if showImages:
        Image.fromarray(img_bin_final).show()

    # Contours Filtering
    _, labels, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)

    squares = 0 # Counter for numbering potential checkboxes
    for x, y, w, h, area in stats[2:]:
        print('rectangle : (x , y) = ', x, y)
        print('size: w, h', w, h)
        # Only draw an rectangle on image within a certain size range, width and height
        if (w < 20) and (w > 5) and (h < 20) and (h > 4):
            print('rectangle ', squares, ': (x , y) = ', x, y)
            print('size: w, h', w, h)
            cv2.rectangle(inputImage, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(inputImage, str(squares), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 255)
            squares += 1

    # Show image with found checkboxes highlighted in red
    if showImages:
        Image.fromarray(inputImage).show()

    # saving file
    if not showImages:
        print('File saved: ', destDir + 'contouredImage-%i.png' % i)
        destFileName = destDir + 'contouredImage-%i.png' % i
        Image.fromarray(inputImage).save(destFileName)

    # Increase counter
    i += 1
```

This results in missing checkboxes and still too many. My next script I try to zoom into the specific area. I don't need to scan the whole document. Just the area where those 3 checkboxes are, using Crop:

https://github.com/Koffiemolen/OpenCVROICheckbox

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
import os
import shutil
import functools
from PIL import Image

# pip install opencv-python numpy scipy Pillow imutils
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866205/detect-whether-the-checkbox-is-checked-using-opencv
# sourceDir = 'C:/Temp/Singer/Output/page-1.png'

path = "C:/Temp/Output/a/"
checkedP = "C:/Temp/checked/"
uncheckedP = "C:/Temp/unchecked/"
included_extensions = ['png', 'PNG']
whitePixelAverage = []
THRESHOLD = 117

allFiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if
            any(f.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)]  # Get all files in current directory

length = len(allFiles)

for i in range(length):
    print(allFiles[i])
    img = cv2.imread(path + allFiles[i])
    # cv2.imshow('Original', img)
    imgCrop = img[1000:1300, 50:110]  # Select your ROI here, I allow for a bit of deviation between image scans
    # cv2.imshow('Cropped', imgCrop)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Converting image to gray scale
    grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(imgCrop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Image thresholding
    _, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 180, 225, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    binaryImage = 255 - binaryImage

    Image.fromarray(binaryImage).show()

    # Using morphological operations to identify edges
    # Set min width to detect horizontal lines
    line_min_width = 7

    # Kernel to detect horizontal lines
    kernel_h = np.ones((1, line_min_width), np.uint8)

    # Kernel to detect vertical lines
    kernel_v = np.ones((line_min_width, 1), np.uint8)

    # Horizontal kernel on image
    img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_h)

    # Vertical kernel on the image
    img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_v)

    # Show image with horizontal lines only and vertical lines only
    # Image.fromarray(img_bin_h).show()
    # Image.fromarray(img_bin_v).show()

    # Combining the image, horizontal + vertical
    img_bin_final = img_bin_h | img_bin_v

    # Show combined image
    # Image.fromarray(img_bin_final).show()

    # some hocus pocus
    final_kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    img_bin_final = cv2.dilate(img_bin_final, final_kernel, iterations=2)
    # Image.fromarray(img_bin_final).show()

    # Contours Filtering
    _, labels, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)

    squares = 0 # Counter for numbering potential checkboxes
    for x, y, w, h, area in stats[2:]:
        print('rectangle : (x , y) = ', x, y)
        print('size: w, h', w, h)
        # Only draw a rectangle on image within a certain size range, width and height
        if 7 <= w <= 13 and 7 <= h <= 13:
            print('rectangle ', squares, ': (x , y) = ', x, y)
            print('size: w, h', w, h)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(squares), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 255)
        squares += 1

    # Show image with found checkboxes highlighted in red
    Image.fromarray(img).show()
```

This got me a little closer but still to many positives.

Comment: locate/register form, warp to match template, extract boxes blindly, analyze regions -- please review [ask]. OMR is a common application but I realize you may not know the term. please do some research.

Comment: I suspect you would do better with a higher resolution.

Comment: eh, I'd say it's a bit small but workable. I'm seeing 144 dpi. traditional OCR will choke on it but who's using decades old tech when we have fully convolutional networks that can do OCR... -- by the way, for document alignment/registration, recognizing glyphs, digraphs/trigraphs, words would give excellent features for matching